# Using Echo within a Batch File to write an IF Statement to a Text File

Tags: batch-file, text, echo

I am working to build a text file which is really a VBA module for Excel but written using a batch file. I want to create it dynamically based on a users selection on a choice menu. The module will create a loop to apply a macro across all files in a folder, but the MACRO can change based on the user input.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the the following line to copy over to the text file:

```
 Echo If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\">>c:\users\%username%\desktop\TESTVBA.vbs
```

All other lines above this line write to the file, but this line and everything below will not follow over, but I believe it has to do with the syntax. How do I block this out to copy over? or can it not be copied over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you're going to `echo` should be escaped. Unfortunately there is no one way solution. Every `%` percent symbol should be dubbed and all special symbols from the list `<>&|` should be escaped with the `^` caret symbol. The following code would be working for you. Please turn your attention how `<>` inequality operator has been mutated to `^<^>`

```
Echo If Right(folderPath, 1) ^<^> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"
```

**Update**

One more thing that I have just remembered. Parentheses `(` and `)` could bring one more headache, if they are going to be `echo`ed within code block (something executable within parentheses).

To eliminate these problems I would like to recommend to store printable massive texts as comments and read them using `for /f`.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me this worked perfectly. I am going to go and check the rest of my code and see if I can't make it all come together.

Comment: So, how would you go about the following:    Echo Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.dbf")>>c:\users\%%username%%\desktop\TESTVBA.vbs

Comment: Because your resulting file is `c:\users\%username%\desktop\TESTVBA.vbs`, you don't need to to dub `%` symbols. But you need to escape `&` symbol here. So the resulting command should look like this one: `Echo Filename = Dir(folderPath ^& "*.dbf")>>c:\users\%username%\desktop\TESTVBA.vbs`.

Comment: Thanks, I know @Magoo mentioned that as well. It's been a long day of coding VBA, VBS, and CMD. I am fried for the day. Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Each of the individual redirector characters (`>`,`<`,`|`) needs to be escaped with a caret (`^`) thus:

```
... th, 1) ^<^> "\"...
```

The same goes for other characters that may provide problems like `&`,`^` and `)` (`)` only within a `code-block` (parenthesised sequence of instructions) in the generat*ing* code)

`%` also needs to be escaped - but the escape character for `%` is another `%`, so `%username%` needs to be coded as `%%username%%` - unless you want to substitute the current value of `username` in the generat*ing* code here.

Comment: You are correct that it should have been %%username%% on that variable, but from the command-line I would have put %username%. I was just typing the code over. Thanks for the catch!